# How to create an array of classes and instance objects with it in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I tried to [ask this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010885/how-to-convert-swift-switch-case-is-block-into-loop-oriented-code) previously but didn't clearly express my question, so I'll try again here. I also noticed a [very similar sounding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145564/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-classes-in-swift), but it is asking for something entirely different.

I have the following code:

```
class Base {
    func launch(code1: Int, code2: Int) { ... }
}

class A: Base {}
class B: Base {}
class C: Base {}

let classes = [A.self, B.self, A.self, B.self, C.self]
for cls in classes {
    let obj = ???
}
```

I would like to instantiate an object of type `cls` inside the loop and do something with it. I might have duplicates inside the array, as shown. What do I put in place of the `???` to be able to instantiate the proper objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is a `required init`, some way to create an instance that will be shared between all `Types` you want this to work for. A `protocol` that holds an init method will do fine.

Obviously this works simplest when the `init` does not require parameters.

Downside is that you do need to downcast the resulting instances.

```
protocol ZeroParamaterInit {
    init()
}

class Base : ZeroParamaterInit {
    func launch(code1: Int, code2: Int) {  }
    required init() {

    }
}

class A: Base {}
class B: Base {}
class C: Base {}

let classes : [ZeroParamaterInit.Type] = [A.self,B.self]
var instances : [Any] = []

for cls in classes {

    let instance = cls.init()
    instances.append(instance)

}

for instance in instances {

    if let test = instance as? A {
        print("A")
    }
    if let test = instance as? B {
        print("B")
    }
    if let test = instance as? C {
        print("C")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you'll love this link:
http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/05/instantiating-classes-by-name-in-swift/

It walks you through the Swift library *Obj
ectFactory*:

https://github.com/ijoshsmith/swift-factory

You really can't do this in Swift. You can, however, do it in Objective-C so you can simply write a wrapper that exposes a Swift interface where behind the scenes, actual object creation is done in Objective-C. That library is exactly what you're looking for.

You'd need to create a ObjectFactory like this:

```
let factory = ObjectFactory<MyClass>
```

Then you can instantiate an instance of *MyClass* like:

```
let myClass1 = factory.createInstance(className: "MyClassName")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

class Base {}

class A: Base { var i: Int = 1 }
class B: Base { var i: String = "bravo" }
class C: Base { var i: Bool = true }

let classes = [A.self, B.self, A.self, B.self, C.self]

for cls in classes {
    var obj: Base? {
        switch cls {
        case is A.Type:
            return A()
        case is B.Type:
            return B()
        case is C.Type:
            return C()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    dump(obj)
}


/*
▿ A
    ▿ Some: A #0
    - super: Base
    - i: 1
▿ B
    ▿ Some: B #0
    - super: Base
    - i: bravo
▿ A
    ▿ Some: A #0
    - super: Base
    - i: 1
▿ B
    ▿ Some: B #0
    - super: Base
    - i: bravo
▿ C
    ▿ Some: C #0
    - super: Base
    - i: true
*/
```

this is very close to R Menke solution ...